# How to update value on input change in JSP?

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have shopping cart with fields `Title` `Price` `Amount` `Total`. Title and price works fine but `Amount` is input field where user can enter how many items he wants and i want to update `Total` based on that.
Here is my JSP:

```
 <body>
    <table border="1px"style="width:50%">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="article" items="${articleList}">              
            <tr>
                <td>${article.title}</td>
                <td>${article.price}</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="${article.numberOfOrder}"  onchange="myFunction()"></td>                    
                <td>${article.total}</td>
                  <input type="hidden" value="${article.numberOfOrder}" name="article_NumberOfOrder">
                  <input type="hidden" value="${article.total}" name="article_total">
                  <input type="hidden" value="${article.price}" name="article_price">
            </tr>
        </c:forEach> <br>
    </table>
    Total:${total}<br>
</body>
```

Below `<body>`i have javacsript where i send to servlet when value(number of orders) is changed:

```
  <script>
function myFunction() {
  document.location.href="ArticalOnChangeServlet";    
}
 </script>
```

And this is servlet:

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    int numberOfOrder = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("articleNumberOfOrder"));//Here i'm getting NPE
    double price = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("article_price"));
    Double totalArtical = (Double)session.getAttribute("totalArticle");
    if(totalArtical == null){
        totalArtical = price;
    }
    totalArtical*=numberOfOrder;
    session.setAttribute("totalArtical", totalArticle);
    ArticleUpdate(numberOfOrder,totalArticle); // Here i update database
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("cart_overview.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

IDE and browser are giving me null pointer exception in servlet on line where i try to get parameter from number of orders. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: In your current code you are just redirecting to servlet without passing any value to your backend that's the reason its returning null.

Comment: @Swati You mean in JS i need to pass value to servlet? But how?

Comment: yes either pass value as parameter in url i.e : `ArticalOnChangeServlet?varibale1=value1..` or use ajax .

Comment: @Swati Okay, that makes sense, but how to pass value in js without going to servlet and typing `request.getParameter("artical_NumberOfOrder")`?For example if i want to pass number of order in js `ArticalOnChangeServlet?artical_NumberOfOrder=` is equal to what?

Comment: put `onchange="myFunction(this.value)"` and change your function i.e : `function myFunction(value)` and pass it in url `"ArticalOnChangeServlet?artical_NumberOfOrder="+value;`

Comment: Yes, thank you! One more question and i want bother you anymore :D
When i want to pass value of a price i give it id="price" and tried this in myFunction: `let x = document.getElementById("price").value` then i just concat x value:`ArticalOnChangeServlet?artical_NumberOfOrder="+value+"&article_price="+x ;` But it always giving me price of first item, wherever I change number of order. So how to get value from a item that i'm changing number of orders?

Comment: Yes it's because you cannot give same id to all inputs that's the reason it's returning only first value.Instead you can pass that value as well in function i.e : `onchange="myFunction(this.value , '${article.price}')` and then get that value inside function.So, your function will look like `function myFunction(value,price)` and pass it in url.

Comment: @Swati Thank you, i really appreciate that you took time and answered my questions!